# Convert a string literal to a variable name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create an instance of a class with the name of a string. For example:

```
sub_string = "tropical"
string = "forest.#{sub_string}"
```

My class Instance should be `foresttropical = Class_name.new` or `forest_tropical = Class_name.new`.

I want to create a class instance with the variable name `foresttropical` or `foresttropical`. Is there any way to do it?

I am using:

```
constantized_var = "forestarea#{x}".capitalize.constantize
constantized_var = Class_name.new
```

In Plane, I want it to be like this:

```
x = "tropical"
"forestarea#{x}" = ClassName.new equals forestareatropical = ClassName.new
x = "subtropical"
"forestarea#{x}" = ClassName.new
```

But it is giving me an error:

```
uninitialized constant Forestareatropical
```

Comment: You want to make the variable from a string or instance of a class from a string?

Comment: Instance of a class from `string`

Comment: Check my answer. You can create instance from string or a variable from a string. whatever u like.

Answer (score 2):

If your class name is ForestTropical then you can do like this to create new class instance.

```
s1 = "forest"
s2 = "tropical"
new_instance = "#{s1}_#{s2}".classify.constantize.new
# new_instance will be the new instance of your class ForestTropical
```

I hope this helps.

**Edit**

As per your requirements it ll be something like this

```
x = "tropical"
instance_variable_set("@forestarea#{x}",ClassName.new)
x = "subtropical"
instance_variable_set("@forestarea#{x}",ClassName.new)
```

Comment: This is it.. It's identical to my answer, just constructing the string differently.

Comment: That is true @rlarcombe but i was unsure what he needed as he mentioned that he needs to construct class from string.

Comment: It was a bit confusing! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid `forest.tropical` as a name for your object, because in Ruby syntax that looks like you are calling a method called `tropical` on an instance called `forest` which I don't think is what you want here.
So, stick with `forest_tropical` as your instance name.

You might try using `instance_variable_set` here:

```
sub_string = "tropical"
string = "forest_#{sub_string}"
instance_variable_set('@'+string, ClassName.new)
```

Now you have `@forest_tropical` which is an instance of the `ClassName` class.

Or, according to your edit, you can do:

```
x = "tropical"
instance_variable_set("@forestarea#{x}", ClassName.new)
x = "subtropical"
instance_variable_set("@forestarea#{x}", ClassName.new)
```

Now you have two instance variables, `@forestareatropical` and `@forestareasubtropical` both of the ClassName class.

Comment: I want the object name should be dynamic.Class name is not changing.

Comment: I edited my answer for you. I think this should give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should consider using hashes with appropriate keys instead. Since your instance variable names are dynamic anyway, I assume that they will be used in a dynamic context, and for this hashes are better suited.